# How to compile PHP with new OpenSSL library

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, compilation, openssl

I am trying to compile PHP with OpenSSL. That works with the default OpenSSL library 0.9.6 by simply configuring with `--with-openssl=/usr`.

However, I have installed a new OpenSSL library 1.0.0 which I would like to compile PHP with. This library lives in `/usr/local/ssl/bin`.

That unfortunately does not work:

```
configure: error: Cannot find OpenSSL's <evp.h>
```

How can I compile PHP with the new OpenSSL library?

Comment: Have you tried configuring it: `--with-openssl=/usr/local`? or `/usr/local/ssl`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

fixed it by recompiling curl as the compiled version of curl was also using the old openssl lib

```
sudo ./configure -disable-shared -with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
```

After compiling curl, also compiled php again --with-openssl=/usr and phpinfo tells me it is using the new openssl lib.

Comment: The suggested command `sudo ./configure -disable-shared -with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl` if for building curl before recompile PHP

Comment: php7.4> 
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=79313
the --with-[option] has changed

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but before compiling (`./configure -disable-shared -with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl`) I removed (`yum openssl-devel`) and it worked

Comment: the yum install openssl-devel worked for me. I was building PHP Version 8 using binary and it was throwing an error because of openssl. But with yum install openssl-devel..the magic happened

Answer (score -2):

For those using MacPorts adding ssl is super simple:

```
$ sudo port install php71-openssl
```

That's it. Ports will recompile php (version 7.1 in this case) with openssl for you.